# How to resize images for list and single page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-images, image, product-list

By default single page pictures is 700x700 px and list pictures is 270x270.

Does anyone know how can i set for example 2000x2000px for this picures?

Is there any xml where i can set this values or  is a resize function that handle this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change product image size from **view.xml**

Copy **view.xml** file from

```
vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/etc/view.xml
```

add **view.xml** to

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourTheme/etc/view.xml
```

You can find out all pages product images here. Change it as per you need.

Let me know if you have any query.